# Pattern match to extract the braces by excluding the last one

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the characters from a expression which is mentioned below

```
private static final String FILTER_X = "userid=UUID.randomUUID();empid=lkjdlfd ;eventType=Usage"
            + ";classid=1" + ";fromDate=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00" + ";toDate=2017-09-11Z10:00:00+1:00"
            + ";(classno=10 or(classno<4 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00));"
            + "(classno=10 or(classno<10 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00))";

StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(FILTER_X, ";");
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokens.nextToken();
            System.out.println(token);
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(token);
            while (m1.find()) {
                System.out.println(m1.group(1));
            }
        }
```

output:

```
> > userid=UUID.randomUUID()
> > 
> > empid=lkjdlfd   eventType=Usage  classid=1
> > fromDate=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00  toDate=2017-09-11Z10:00:00+1:00
> > (classno=10 or(classno<4 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00))
> > classno=10 or(classno<4 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00
> > (classno=10 or(classno<10 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00))
> > classno=10 or(classno<10 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00
```

I am trying to filter the string which starts with braces. For the above pattern it prints the string within braces 
But it is not printing the last braces i am expecting the output as

> (classno=10 or(classno<4 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00))

which means it should skip the last brace alone. can anyone tell me what is wrong with the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lazy quantifier in your regex. That is causing regex engine to stop matching shortest match between `(` and `)`.

You can make regex lazy, and avoid a capturing group since your expected result is complete match between `(` and `)`.

```
final static String FILTER_X = "userid=UUID.randomUUID();empid=lkjdlfd ;eventType=Usage"
        + ";classid=1" + ";fromDate=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00" + ";toDate=2017-09-11Z10:00:00+1:00"
        + ";(classno=10 or(classno<4 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00));"
        + "(classno=10 or(classno<10 and joiningDate>=2017-08-11Z10:00:00+1:00))";

final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)");
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(FILTER_X, ";");
while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokens.nextToken();
    System.out.println("> : " + token);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(token);
    while (m1.find()) {
        System.out.println(">> : " + m1.group());
    }
}
```

Also better to make `Pattern` final and keep it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to filter the string which starts with braces.

My approach:

```
(?<=^|.;)\([^;\n]+(?=;|$)

(?<=      # Assert this group matches
^|.;      # Start of line OR 1 char, then a semicolon
)         # End of assertion
\([^;\n]+ # An opening brace, then one or more chars of not a semicolon OR a newline
(?=       # Assert this group matches
;|$       # A semicolon OR end-of-line
)         # End of assertion
```

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/3CvE84/1)